# Form Validation (valid, dirty, touched) with Custom Input Component

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I've inherited a project that has a number of components created for various input types (text, checkbox, radio etc.), the forms are not using reactive and at this point it would be too much work to change over

I want to be able to check the form for the states - valid, dirty, touched before submitting or navigating away, but the states from the input controls are not getting propagated up to the form, I can see in dev tools that the inputs themselves are changing state as I edit them

Here's a text input control:

Template:

```
<div [className]="className" [style]="styleName">
    
      <label [className]="labelClass"  for="input_{{id}}" 
             [style]="labelStyle"     
             [translateParams]="labelParam" translate>
             <span [innerHTML]="label|translate:labelParam"></span>
             <ng-content></ng-content>
      </label>

      <div *ngIf="hintText" [className]="hintClass"  [innerHTML]="hintText|translate:hintParam"
                                [style]="hintlStyle"></div>

      
          <input type="{{type}}"  id="input_{{id}}"
                 [className]="inputClass"
                 [style]="inputStyle"
                 [attr.disabled]="disable?true:null"
                 [placeholder]="placeholder"
                 [(ngModel)]="input"

                 [size]="size"
                 [maxlength]="max"

                  oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)"
                  (input)="valueChanged()"
                  (blur)="onBlur()"
                 (focus)="onFocus()"
                 (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)"
                 attr.aria-describedby="error_{{id}}"/>
      

       <div [hidden]="!error" 
            [className]="errorClass" 
            [style]="errorStyle" id="error_{{id}}">
                  <b>{{!error? '':'error.prefix'| translate}}</b>
                  <span class="" [innerHTML]="error|translate:errorParam" ></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

Component class:

```
import { Component,OnInit,  AfterViewInit, ElementRef,Input,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlBaseComponent } from "../control-base.component";
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
import { TimerService } from 'src/refresh/service/timer-service';
import { Util } from 'src/refresh/service/Util';


@Component({ 
  selector: 'ng-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.less']
})       
export class InputComponent extends ControlBaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
       //--------------------------------------------------------------------
       private static id_no:number = 1;
        
       @Input() size: number = 16;
       @Input() type: string = "text";
       @Input() max:  number;
       @Input() placeholder: string = "";
       @Input() option:  number;

       @Output('blur')   blurChange  = new EventEmitter<any>();
       @Output('focus')  focusChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
       //@Output('change')  : this works , fire when blured.

      // private controlMargin = "control-margin "
       //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        public get className():string {
             //return this.controlMargin + this.class_name;
             return this.class_name;
        }

        public get inputClass():string {
               return "input-class " + this.input_class;
        }

        public get labelClass():string {
               return "input-label "+this.label_class;
        }

        private inputCtrl:any;

        constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private device: DeviceDetectorService,protected timerService:TimerService) { 
                    super(timerService,3);
        }  

        private inline:any;
        public ngOnInit(): void {

               
               this.inputCtrl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
               this.inline    = this.inputCtrl.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("inline");
               
               if ( this.inline != null  && this.inline !==  'false' ) {
                    this.inline = true;
                    if ( this.label_class )  this.label_class += " inline";
                    else                     this.label_class = "inline";

                    this.labelStyle = "margin-right:0.44em";
                    ///this.controlMargin = "";
               }
               else if ( !this.class_name ) this.class_name = "control-margin ";


               if ( !this.id ) {
                     this.id = this.type+"_"+InputComponent.id_no++;
               }

               if ( !this.max ) {
                     this.max = this.size;
               }

               if ( this.option ) {
                    this.controlType = this.option;
               }

               super.errorParamSet();
        }

        public ngAfterViewInit() {

            if ( this.type == "number" || this.type == "tel" ) {  
                 this.inputCtrl.style.width = this.size + "em";
                 ////this.inputCtrl.style.textAlign="center";
            }

            if ( this.size >= 29 && this.device.isMobile() ) {
                 this.inputCtrl.style.width = "100%";
            }
              
            super.layoutFromViewInit(this.inputCtrl.parentElement);
        }

      
        public onBlur() {
               if ( this.type == "number" ) {
                    let value:number = null;
                    if ( this.input || this.input == '0' )  value = parseInt(this.input);
                    this.inputChange.emit(value);
                    this.blurChange.emit(value);
                    return;
               }

               if ( this.input ) this.input = Util.trim(this.input);
               
               this.inputChange.emit(this.input);
               this.blurChange.emit(this.input);
               this.timerService.reset();
        }

        public onFocus() {
               this.focusChange.emit(this.input);
               this.timerService.reset();
        }
      
        public onKeyPress(event:any) {
              if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                   this.inputCtrl.blur();
              }
              else
              if ( this.type == 'tel' ) {
                   if ( event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                   } 
              }
        }
}
```

And you can see it extends a common base component that all other input controls also use:

```
import { Input,Output,EventEmitter,Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutBaseComponent } from "../layout/layout-base.component";
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { TimerService } from 'src/refresh/service/timer-service';

@Directive()
export class ControlBaseComponent extends LayoutBaseComponent {

       public static errorClassByLang:string = "input-error-en ";

       protected _inputX:any;

       @Input ('ng-model')  set input( value: any) {
                this._inputX = value;
       }

       get input() {
           return this._inputX;
       }

       @Output('ng-modelChange')  inputChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
              
       @Input ("error-param")    errorParam: any;
       @Input ("error-if")       errorWhere: any;

       constructor(protected timerService:TimerService,protected controlType:number) {
                      super();
       }

       public _error:string;

       get  error():string {
            return this._error;
       }

       @Input ("ng-error") set error( theValue: string) {

              if ( theValue && theValue.endsWith("$") ) {

                  let  where = this.errorWhere;

                  if ( where === undefined  ) where = this.generalIf;

                  if ( where !== undefined  ) {

                        if ( typeof where  == 'string' ) {
                             if ( where ) theValue += where;
                        }
                        else
                        if ( where )  theValue += "Y";
                        else          theValue += "N";
                  }
              }

              this._error = theValue;

              if ( environment.production == false )  this.errorCode = theValue;
       }

       @Output("ng-errorChange") errorChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

       @Input ('ng-clear')       clearField: any;
       @Output("ng-clearChange") clearFieldChange = new EventEmitter<string>();


       public  _disable:boolean;

       @Input('ng-disable')  set  disable(value:boolean) {

              this._disable = value;
               
              if ( value )  {
                   //if ( typeof this.input == 'boolean' ) 
                   //     this.input = false;
                   //else this.input = "";

                   if ( this.label_class ) this.label_class += " disable-grey";
                        this.label_class = " disable-grey";

                   ///setTimeout( () => this.inputChange.emit(this.input),1);                
              }
              else {
                   let idx = this.label_class.indexOf("disable-grey");
                   if ( idx >= 0 ) {
                        this.label_class = this.label_class.substring(0,idx).trim();
                   }
              }
       }

       get disable():boolean {
              return this._disable;
       }
       
       public get errorClass():string {
              return "input-error " + ControlBaseComponent.errorClassByLang + this.error_class;
       }

       @Input ("error-class")  error_class: string = "";
       @Input ("error-style")  errorStyle: string;
        
       public get hintClass():string {
            return "hint-text " + this.hint_class;
       }
       @Input ('hint-text')        hintText: string;
       @Input ('hint-class')       hint_class: string = "";
       @Input ('hint-style')       hintStyle: string;
       @Input ('hint-param')       hintParam: string;

       public errorCode:string = "";

       public asIsOrder(a, b) {
              return 0;
       }  


       protected errorParamSet() {

             super.labelCheck();
             
             if ( this.input === undefined ) {
                 // console.log("*undef*", this.id, "*"+(this.error||''))
             }

             if ( this.errorParam && this.errorParam.length >= 0  ) {
                 if ( this.errorParam.charAt(0) == '{' ) {
                      this.errorParam = eval("("+this.errorParam+")");
                 }
             }          

             if ( this.labelParam && this.labelParam.length >= 0  ) {
                  if ( this.labelParam.charAt(0) == '{' ) {
                       this.labelParam = eval("("+this.labelParam+")");
                  }
             }          

             if ( this.hintParam && this.hintParam.length >= 0  ) {
                  if ( this.hintParam.charAt(0) == '{' ) {
                       this.hintParam = eval("("+this.hintParam+")");
                  }
             }          
       }

       public valueChanged() {

            if ( this.controlType != 3 ) {
                 this.inputChange.emit(this.input); 
                 this.timerService.reset();
            }

            if ( this.error ) {
                 this.errorChange.emit("");
                 this.error = null;
            }

            if ( this.clearField ) {
                 this.clearField = null;
                 this.clearFieldChange.emit(this.clearField);
            }
       }
}
```

Then finally a sample usage:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
            <ng-input [(ng-model)]="myModel.name" id="name" 
                    [(ng-error)]="error_name" class="input-bottom"     
                    size="53" max="80"></ng-input>
</form>
```

As I said, when editing the value in the text input control I can see that the class changes to ng-dirty and ng-touched but when checking myForm it is not inheriting the states

I've seen similar questions with answers relating to not using ngModel within the custom component, but I'm not quite sure I understand how to properly do it with what I have

Side related q, what would be the best way to add the 'required' tag to the controls so I can also use ng-valid?